# How to query GCP tables fast

Tags: python, performance, api, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to build a small api which returns data from Google Cloud Platform public table.
Currently I am trying to get the data with python but querying the table takes forever cause it has millions of rows. Is there a way to query the table, while excluding null etc and return response to client in under 2 minutes? And if yes how, should I do it somehow async?
My current code is :

```
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_storage
import pandas
import pandas_gbq
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    **you need service account credentials**
)
sql = SELECT passenger_count, trip_distance, pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude, dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2016`
WHERE pickup_longitude IS NOT NULL AND pickup_latitude IS NOT NULL 
AND dropoff_longitude IS NOT NULL AND dropoff_latitude IS NOT NULL
AND passenger_count < 7 AND passenger_count > 0
AND pickup_longitude != 0.0 AND pickup_latitude  != 0.0 
AND dropoff_longitude  != 0.0 AND dropoff_latitude  != 0.0
```

and I use pandas:

```
df = pandas_gbq.read_gbq(sql,project_id='disco-parsec-303220',credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: You are forcing BigQuery to read every row. Try creating a temporary table with just the results from `passenger_count < 7 AND passenger_count > 0` and then query the temporary table with the rest of your query requirements. Also, update your question on what you are running your code on with details, include the public table name and post a minimum reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JohnHanley What do you mean a temp table so a temp table like 
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE passenger_count < 7 AND passenger_count > 0 
And then on this table the rest of the requirements? Will this speed it up?

Comment: Did you update your question with the details requested? I made a suggestion, test and verify.

Comment: Yes, i did edit it :)

Answer (score 0):

[Use the BigQuery Storage API to download large results faster](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration#using_the_to_download_large_results).

I got your results in ~1min.

```
import pandas

sql ="SELECT passenger_count, trip_distance, pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude, dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude
        FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2016`
        WHERE pickup_longitude IS NOT NULL
            AND pickup_latitude IS NOT NULL
            AND dropoff_longitude IS NOT NULL
            AND dropoff_latitude IS NOT NULL
            AND passenger_count < 7 AND passenger_count > 0
            AND pickup_longitude != 0.0 AND pickup_latitude  != 0.0
            AND dropoff_longitude  != 0.0 AND dropoff_latitude  != 0.0"

df = pandas.read_gbq(sql, dialect='standard', use_bqstorage_api=True)
```

You should be able to get even faster results with the `google-cloud-bigquery` library and Apache Arrow ([Reference](https://friendliness.dev/2019/07/29/bigquery-arrow/))